# Filter portal for most recently created record by group

Tags: filemaker

I have a portal on my "Clients" table. The related table contains the results of surveys that are updated over time. For each combination of client and category (a field in the related table), I only want the portal to display the most recently collected row.

[Here is a link to a trivial example that illustrates the issue I'm trying to address](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysblspw73om1ftw/Portal%20Show%20last%20By%20Group%20for%20Stack%20Overflow.fmp12?dl=0). I have two tables in this example (Related on ClientID):

- Clients
- Table 1 Get Summary Method

The Table 1 Get Summary Method table looks like this:
[image]

Where:

- MaxDate is a summary field = Maximum of Date
- MaxDateGroup is a calculated field = GetSummary ( MaxDate ;
  ClientIDCategory )
- ShowInPortal = If ( Date = MaxDateGroup ; 1 ; 0 )
- The table is sorted on ClientIDCategory

**Issue 1 that I'm stumped on:** .
ShowInPortal should equal 1 in row 3 (PKTable01 = 5), row 4 (PKTable01 = 6), and row 6 (PKTable01 = 4) in the table above. I'm not sure why FM is interpreting 1Red and 1Blue as the same category, or perhaps I'm just misunderstanding what the GetSummary function does.

The Clients table looks like this:
[image]

Where:

- The portal records are sorted on ClientIDCategory

**Issue 2 that I'm stumped on:**
I only want rows with a ShowInPortal value equal to 1 should appear in the portal. I tried creating a portal filter with the following formula: Table 1 Get Summary Method::ShowInPortal = 1. However, using that filter removes all row from the portal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting MaxDateGroup in the portal to see what is calculated for each row?

Comment: Hi @AndreasT, I was able to fix issue 1. The calculation used for MaxDateGroup was returning a number instead of text. This caused it to ignore the "Red" and "Blue". Still can't figure out issue 2 though. I added MaxDateGroup to the portal, but I didn't see how it would have helped with issue 2.

Comment: Well, seems to me that the issue is that the portal filter operates before the sort, meaning that there wont be any records where the ShowInPortal field evaluates to true, as the portal need to be sorted for the getsummary to work. So ShowInPortal is always false in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use ExecuteSQL to grab the Max Date. This removes the need for Summary functions and sorts, and works as expected. Propose to return it as number to avoid any issues with date formats.

```
GetAsTimestamp ( 
    ExecuteSQL (
    "SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(MaxDate,'')
        FROM Survey 
    WHERE ClientIDCategory = ? "
    ; "" ; "";ClientIDCategory )
)
```

Also, you need to change the ShowInPortal field to an unstored calc field with:

```
If ( GetAsNumber(Date) = MaxDateGroupSQL ; 1 ; 0 )
```

Then filter the portal on this field.

I can send you the sample file if you want.

Comment: Hi @AndreasT. Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working for me. I cut and pasted your code chunk above into the calculation for MaxDate. When I add new records to the Survey table MaxDate is blank.

Comment: Uploaded the sample file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgd9ke51q3o5tco/Portal%20Show%20last%20By%20Group%20for%20Stack%20Overflow.fmp12.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Works! Thank you!